# Why for Rambam learning and teaching Torah are not two different Mitzvos?

Tags: halacha-theory, torah-study, rambam, mitzvah

Rambam in [Sefer Hamitzvos #11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaMitzvot%2C_Positive_Commandments.11.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) and in Mishne Torah Hil. Talmud Torah  rules that studying and teaching Torah are one Mitzvah:

> היא שצונו ללמוד תורה וללמדה וזהו הנקרא תלמוד תורה,
>   והוא אמרו ושננתם לבניך

1. We can see that in many other cases he seemingly splits one commandment into several distinctive Mitzvos, like two Teffilin or honoring and fearing parents.
2. In many cases, the Gemmorah wants to emphasize G-d's intention to multiply our merits by doubling our Mitzvos (or transgressions) so it would be plausible to count it as two Mitzvos.
3. Also there are numerous different Psukim for either learning or teaching Torah, for example, the Posuk:

   > "וְשִׁנַּנְתָּם לְבָנֶיךָ וְדִבַּרְתָּ בָּם בְּשִׁבְתְּךָ בְּבֵיתֶךָ וּבְלֶכְתְּךָ בַדֶּרֶךְ וּבְשָׁכְבְּךָ וּבְקוּמֶךָ"

   can be understood as two: ושננתם (teach) and ודברת (learn).

So why did Rambam combine the two into one Mitzvah?

Comment: To provide chochmat hatora to oneself and to others may be the same principle

Comment: I was hoping Rav Yerucham Fischel Perla would [address it](https://www.sefaria.org/Commentary_on_Sefer_Hamitzvot_of_Rasag%2C_Positive_Commandments.14?lang=he) but he seems to simply ask your question on the Rambam and doesn't seem answer it (as usual, his commentary is very long, so I might have missed it). He points out that the Semak counts it as two mitzvos, and the Bahag et. al actually counts it as three

Comment: What would be the two separate pesukim/commandments in the Torah?